# PHP get first few charactors and remove from string

Tags: php

Does anyone know how to remove the first few characters from a string and remove them in PHP.

Like in the string "str_filename" I need to remove the "str_" and save the "filename".

But it has to remove as many charactors as it takes to get to the "_".

In other words, i need to remove all the characters up until and including the first "_" in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
if (strpos($string, '_') !== false)
   $string = substr($string, strpos($string, '_') + 1);
```

It works as you can see here: http://codepad.org/g12ENLGY

**Note**: The `if` is useful because your string could not have the '_' char.

Comment: Btw, usually people do `if (false !== $pos = strpos($string, '_')) $string = substr($string, $pos + 1);` to save the duplicate strpos ;)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use something like:

```
$files = explode("_", $filename);
echo $files[1];
```

So this would split the string on the `_` character, and then echo the second part (after the underscore).

This assumes that there is only one underscore though.

Please see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Good that you specify that this solution works only with one underscore. ;)

Answer (score 1):

An additional solution than using `explode` and `substr` as have been mentioned you can solve it using regex:

```
^(?:[^_]*_)(.*)$
```

Here's an example using it:

```
$str = "str_filename";
$pattern = "/^(?:[^_]*_)(.*)$/";
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; //prints "filename"
```